# why need to resample to isotropic reosolution when using 3D CNN

Tags: 3d, resolution, conv-neural-network, resampling

In [this part](https://www.kaggle.io/svf/928737/59dc24cd622cbc31fa90a5d50ec706ef/__results__.html#Resampling) of the [2017 kaggle data science bowl preprocessing tutorial kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/gzuidhof/full-preprocessing-tutorial#resampling), the author says the different spacing between scans "can be problematic for automatic analysis (e.g. using ConvNets)", and then demonstrates the method of "resampling the full dataset to a certain isotropic resolution".

I wonder what kind of problem will arise if we don't resample to isotropic resolution? Would anyone give a theoretic explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If the scans are not of the same resolution, than the spacing between pixels will be different distances. These pixels, or more appropriately, voxels, will represent a different sized volume of space. This means that the data from separate scans are representing something a little different. Typical ConvNets are not scale invariant, which may be where the trouble arises. They can have trouble detecting features of different sizes, especially if they were not in the training set.